# Submit form and get error code 422 Unprocessable Entity with testing Rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara

I am using capybara interactive with form

```
  select_visible(@state, "form label[for='state']+div.field a.chosen-single")
  select_visible(@platform, "form label[for='platform']+div.field a.chosen-single")
  if @appstore_search != nil && @appstore_search != ""
    page.find("#autocomplete_chosen a").click
    page.find("#autocomplete_chosen div.chosen-drop div.chosen-search input[type='text']").set(@appstore_search)
    if page.has_css?("#autocomplete_chosen ul.chosen-results li.active-result")
      page.find("#autocomplete_chosen ul.chosen-results li:nth-child(3)").click
    else
      fill_in('name', :with => @appstore_search)
    end
  else
    fill_in('name', :with => @name)
  end

  click_button 'Save'

  if page.find("form label[for='platform']+div")[:class].include?("field invalid")
    @warning_platform = page.find("form label[for='platform']+div.field.invalid aside.error-message").text
    puts @warning_platform
  end

  if page.find("form label[for='name']+div")[:class].include?("field invalid")
    @warning_name = page.find("form label[for='name']+div.field.invalid aside.error-message").text
    puts @warning_name
  end

  if page.has_css?('#alerts ul li')
    @message = page.find("#alerts ul li").text
    puts @message
  end
```

I can fill in all text boxes, but I can't send the `fill_in('name', :with => @appstore_search)`

I got the Error

```
    {
    "status": 422,
    "result": {
        "error": "Invalid parameter 'name' value nil: Must be String"
    }
}
```

Can anyone suggest me a solution?

Comment: How do you know that it's `fill_in('name', :with => @appstore_search)` line which is creating this issue?

Comment: because i set value for @appstore_search so i thinks that is fill_in('name', :with => @appstore_search)

Comment: i set @appstore_search = a then capybara fill_in  input text with value = a

Comment: just a general comment, if your tests contain if/else constructs, that's considered a code smell. tests should yield reproducible results, don't split your code-paths, it will result in hard to debug code as a result.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, so this isn't quite an answer, but here is what I would do to debug this (and yes get rid of these ifs, you should have separate tests for different scenarios).

```
   select_visible(@state, "form label[for='state']+div.field a.chosen-single")
   select_visible(@platform, "form label[for='platform']+div.field a.chosen-single")
   puts "appstore_search: #{@appstore_search}"
   puts "name: #{@name}"
      if @appstore_search != nil && @appstore_search != ""
        puts 'appstore_search is present'
        page.find("#autocomplete_chosen a").click
        page.find("#autocomplete_chosen div.chosen-drop div.chosen-search input[type='text']").set(@appstore_search)
        if page.has_css?("#autocomplete_chosen ul.chosen-results li.active-result")
          puts 'page has autocomplete css'
          page.find("#autocomplete_chosen ul.chosen-results li:nth-child(3)").click
        else
          puts 'filling in name with App Store search'
          fill_in('name', :with => @appstore_search)
        end
      else
        puts 'filling in name with name'
        fill_in('name', :with => @name)
      end
      save_and_open_page
      click_button 'Save'
```

And hopefully all those puts will help you follow where your code is going. Then the save and open page will show you visually what is in the name box prior to clicking save.